# Simple harmonic motion..direction of acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, harmonic-oscillator, spring

To solve questions about simple harmonic motion, my book says $\ddot{x}$ (i.e. acceleration) is in the direction of *increasing* $x$, i.e. **away** from equilibrium. I don't understand why is this so, since I know that the restoring force, hence acceleration, are directed **towards** the equilibrium point. Please tell me what am I missing out?

Comment: I think it applies to the absolute value of acceleration which _is_ increasing

Comment: Can you show the actual passage in the book saying this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this post (v3) until the precise reference and context of the quote are given.

Answer (score 0):

I think it applies to the absolute value of acceleration which *is* increasing.

$\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}​ m \vect{\ddot x} = -D \vect{x}$

$ \vect{\ddot x} = -\dfrac{D}{m} \vect x$

hence

$ |\vect{\ddot x}| \sim |\vect x| $

Notes: $\dfrac D m$ is a positive constant describing the system. $D$ is the spring constant of the oscillator (sometimes also called $k$) and $m$ is the mass of the object that is oscillating. As you can see, the bigger $\vect x$ is, the bigger acceleration you get, just in the reverse direction. If you are interested, I can prove that  $\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}​ m \vect{\ddot x} = -D \vect{x}$ equations fulfills the definition of harmonic oscillation.

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: By "absolute" u mean we are considering only the 'magnitude' of acceleration,right? Which is obviously increasing, I do get u. But how can we just ignore the direction when solving mechanics?! As you have said, acceleration is "in the **reverse** direction" to x. Now my doubt is; why then do we solve questions using the idea that acceleration is in the **same** direction as x, and magically (actually mathematically!) it turns out to be right, while shallowly looking at the method, it **seems**  incorrect. (P.S. Please indicate if i should have posted this on the Maths forum instead) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are discussing a certain time frame. Type this into wolfram. " x''+x=0, x'(0)=0, x(0)=1 " --->x=cos(t) This is equivalent to pulling a spring to displacement 1 and letting it go. The spring will oscillate back and fourth between 1 and -1. The plot is a time vs. position plot. Now take the derivative ----> x=-sin(t) this is a time vs. velocity plot. take the derivative again ----> x=-cos(t). This is a time vs. acceleration plot. Plot all of these on a graph in different colors and you will be able to see what is going on. There is a time when x is moving in the positive direction and acceleration is positive. when the spring becomes fully compressed and barely begins moving in the positive direction again the acceleration is positive because the mass on the end of the spring is speeding up. I don't know what level of mathematics or physics you are taking, so I have tried to answer you simply.

Comment: Can you please extend on the second part:''the spring compressed...mass accelerating''. Please feel free to make the explanation as detailed as you wish. As for the first part, I could make out you are referring to this but there are no positive acceleration and x at the same time so it is possibly you meant something else idk really cause Sorry i don't get what to type into wolfram exactly (p.s. never used it before), it's not returning any results for the whole phrase, can you paste a link to something else maybe please. However,

Comment: Sorry (continuation) ... I could make out your referring to this http://imgur.com/QoaITxm